# Floating Action Button issue in Samsung Galaxy Tab only

Tags: android, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

First check Image then read it.

I have added FAB in my android application of Design support library ...
But it's not inflating propely..
I have tried in every resolution and 7inch, 10inch, and every tablet. It's displaying correctly.

What i have already done ..
   -> Put all bucket images mhdpi, lhdi, xhdpi, xxhdpi
   -> Tried all emulator of different sizes
   -> It's working properly in all my nexus, samsung Grand, Lenovo

But only issue is in Galaxy Tab SMT10..
it's look like below Image , and here is my xml

[image]

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_camera"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/btn_selected_color"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/gv_photo_galary"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: check the question is edited

Comment: Is your FAB inside `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Yes it is in RelativeLayout

Comment: Try to remove `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"`

Comment: And remove `app:layout_anchor="@+id/gv_photo_galary"`

Comment: can u explain why should i have to remove this??

Comment: Because I think its not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105974/discussion-between-moinkhan-and-mr-icetea).